# Is there a way to validate a GA client Id in realtime?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm currently trying to validate if a GA client ID is valid in realtime. I am currently using the userActivity search (passing in client ID) from Reporting API V4 and attempting to get results back (which would indicate that it is valid). However, I noticed that for a new GA client ID, it would take upwards to about 10-15 minutes before their client ID returns any results (same with the User Explorer on the web page).

Is there a way to validate a GA client ID in realtime?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "valid"? GA will accept basically everything as client id (even if they have a recommended format, to whit UUID). If you implement a client id manually, it is your responsibility to make sure it's unique per user.

Comment: Currently, we only have a frontend using GA and are not implementing the client id manually ourselves. We just create it using `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');`.

We are planning to create a simple backend to generate a discount code associated to a unique GA client ID, but we want to make sure that the id passed to the backend is valid (as it is a public endpoint and we do not have user accounts right now). We don't want someone to call our API with a non-existent GA client ID and receive a discount code that way.